# ObservableArray Knockout doesn't update the view

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockoutJs and i have a problem with an observableArray.

here is the code :

```
var productOid = this.product._oid;
for (var oid in this.basket.dataProvider.persistentBasketItems) {
    var item = this.basket.dataProvider.persistentBasketItems[oid];
    var reference = this.basket.dataProvider.references[item.referenceOid];
    if (!reference) continue;
    if (reference.productOid == productOid) {
        for (var i = 0; i < item.productComplements.length; i++) {
            complements.push(item.productComplements[i]);
        }
        break;
    }
}
this.complements = ko.observableArray(complements);
var grid = this.grid();
if (grid)
    grid.updateComplements();
```

And this is the html code :

```
<span data-bind="text: $parent.complements[openRank]"></span>
```

The openRank attribute is defined on the view model binded on the view.

As you can see in the screenShot below, data are present on the array.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkgWb.png)

Any one can help ?

Best regards,

Comment: I'll add this comment you never know it may help.
I have a drop down list on the page or I can select data display mode, if I change mode (without page refresh), I can see the data in the UI

Comment: Nope, sorry, I don't understand what your problem is?

Comment: here's a small video to explain exactly what is happening: http://expirebox.com/download/a02facfbeba73fb250ed282baab12482.html

Comment: `openRank` is an observable?

Comment: Nope, it's juste a simple attribute in the viewModel.

Answer (score 2):

If the `openRank` was an `observable` try this:

```
<span data-bind="text: $parent.complements()[openRank()]"></span>
```

If not, change it to be an `observable`, because the knockout needs to know that a change was occured to update the view.

see the snippet:

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  this.pos = ko.observable(0);
    this.list = ko.observableArray(["item 1","item 2"]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="number" data-bind="value: pos">
<span data-bind="text: list()[pos()]"></span>
```

Comment: Here is the code:                                                                                     for (var i = 0; i < this.basketColumns.length; i++) {
        var column = this.basketColumns[i];
        if (column.contentType == 'open') {
            column.openRank = ko.observable(n++);
        }
    } but it's not working

Comment: @kbourzayq change to this: `for (var i = 0; i < this.basketColumns.length; i++) 
{ 
 var column = this.basketColumns[i]; 
 if (column.contentType == 'open')
 {
   column.openRank(n++);
  } 
 }`

Comment: i do it in my initial code :( but it's not working also.